# wpf datagrid row edit beginning event to add new row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid with 3 columns which is bound to a collection of a class with 3 properties. 
I want to add a new row as a row is starting to be edited. Right now default WPF behavior is : Type whole row , then click enter or lose focus to add new row. I want row to be added when current row edit BEGINS .

There doesn't seem to be any Row editing beginning event . which i can latch onto and programmatically add empty Person i.e new row.

Is there a less hacky and elegant wya to do this ?

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Team}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

VIEW MODEL :

```
public class WindowViewModel2:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Person> team;

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Team
        {
            get { return team; }
            set
            {
                team = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public WindowViewModel2()
        {
            team=new ObservableCollection<Person>();

            Team.Add(new Person(){Name="P" ,Gender="M",Number="123"});
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



    }
```

CLASs:
public class Person:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AddingNewItem Event added in .NET 4.5 to the DataGrid, which occurs before a new item is added to the DataGrid.

If .NET 4.5 is not an option, I would turn off CanUserAddRows, and then create a button that directly adds a new item to your collection bound to ItemsSource and in that button you can do any initialization or calculations you need and then the user can edit the rest in the DataGrid. This is the technique I often use for my deletes, instead of using the built in CanUserDeleteRows.